# Trigger a Node.js event from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, apache, node.js, nginx

I have a PHP script running and supposedly I'd like to trigger Node.js firing an event to the client side when certain PHP logic has been fulfilled, how should I do it? The Node.js part is still yet to be set up, but will probably be on a different server other than the PHP/Apache one, and being put behind an Nginx which functions as a reverse proxy.

Comment: So the original request comes from the client and goes to PHP, right? Then you want to call some Node.js code that sends stuff to the client?

Comment: Exactly. Say if an user logs out from one browser tab, I'd like to emit a Node.js event to all other tabs of my site so the client-side JS can update verification-related codes accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. "I'd like to emit a Node.js event to all other tabs of my site" - your site doesn't "have tabs". All your PHP server is aware of is the original request. Or are you using websockets?

Comment: @Kay It's possible with websocket. http://socket.io/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8000/'); /* Node app*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Review:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with your php server to a node.js server, yes.

See the NodeLog Class on this page as an example,

http://gonzalo123.com/2011/05/09/real-time-monitoring-php-applications-with-websockets-and-node-js/

It's just a socket at the end of the day.